# Converting the day+week of the month to a date

Tags: python, shell, datetime

I'm trying to come up with a script to covert the following data into a date and time:
The raw data looks like this:

default_maintenance:
hour_start: 13
minute_duration: 120
week: 3
weekday: 2

I'm guessing pulling off the DB will put it in a table like this:

[excel sheet table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPc2l.png)

This would be a different date each month obviously, so how do I turn this data into a date? (I think i will need to run this at least every month to find the corresponding dates.

Using either bash or python would be my preference. I'm very much a beginner at python and recently learned about the datetime module in python and it seemed promising.

Comment: Just for clarification: Is the duration required in your conversion? I.e., do you want the date/time at the end of the "duration" or beginning? Is "week" the week within the current month, or the week from the start of the year? Are you assuming you conversion will be done in the current year?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you know the month and year (and that the week is the week within the known month starting on week 1) you could use `datetime` and `re` as follows:

```py
import datetime
import re

# the string containing the information to extract
dstr = "default_maintenance: hour_start: 13 minute_duration: 120 week: 3 weekday: 2"

# the format of this string for parsing by re
fstr = "default_maintenance: hour_start: (\d+) minute_duration: (\d+) week: (\d+) weekday: (\d+)"

m = re.compile(fstr)

# extract the relevant numbers from the string
datenumbers = m.match(dstr).groups()

hr = datenumbers[0]
dur = datenumbers[1]
week = datenumbers[2]
day = datenumbers[3]

currentmonth = 9
currentyear = 2020

# day at the start of the current month (in days from start of the year)
startday = int(datetime.datetime(currentyear, currentmonth, 1).strftime("%j"))

# get the day of our data
curday = startday + (int(week) - 1) * 7 + int(day)

# convert everything into the date
date = datetime.datetime.strptime(str(currentyear)+str(curday)+hr, "%Y%j%H")

print(date.isoformat())
2020-09-17T13:00:00
```

This assumes that the duration is not relevant.